# Perforce automatically replace symlink with target file when doing add/edit

Tags: perforce

Now I have some large files somewhere and I linked them(ln -s ...) to my client path(not using copy, just want to speed up this step and save disk space). Then I used `p4 add/edit -t <type> <file>` cmd. Every time after the cmd entered, the symbolic link would be replaced with original file automatically.
Just want to know why and how to avoid the replacement.

Comment: What filetype did you specify?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish by adding the symlink?  If you just add a symlink that points outside your client root, nothing is actually being submitted to the depot (any other machine that syncs down the symlink is just getting a broken link).

Comment: An exact transcript of the commands you ran, and the state of the local files before and after, would be necessary to diagnose this.  I don't think that exactly what you said happened is what happened, but it's impossible to figure out what part of the story is wrong without seeing more information.

Comment: I think i have known the reason. The issue only happens on those files whose owner are not me. Perforce do the replacement since it needs to change the file permission everytime after p4 edit/submit.